# Use or operator in jq

Tags: arrays, if-statement, syntax, jq, boolean-operations

I'm using jq to parse JSON. The JSON has an array called "players[]" which contains a key "name" with the following sample values:

```
ZZZ-104TH-082-ADV-004
ZZZ-149TH-435-ADV-WL-006
GDS-123-CIC-007_temp-blocked
LRMR-121-CIC-002_temp-removed
NOS-343-CIC-003_Failed
E180TH-426-CIC-008
LBRTY-185-CIC-005
```

I have this jq line:

`jq '.players[] | if .name | contains( "ZZZ" ) then empty else .name end'`

Which returns the following names:

```
GDS-123-CIC-007_temp-blocked
LRMR-121-CIC-002_temp-removed
NOS-343-CIC-003_Failed
E180TH-426-CIC-008
LBRTY-185-CIC-005
```

I would like to also exclude names that contain "Failed" or "temp" which would return the following:

```
E180TH-426-CIC-008
LBRTY-185-CIC-005
```

I tried

`jq '.players[] | if .name | contains( "ZZZ" ) or contains( "Failed" ) then empty else .name end'`

But that only excluded the names containing "ZZZ". how can I filter out names that contain "ZZZ" or "Failed" or "temp"?

Comment: Your query should work, see this [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Z7e0WXbD-3z).

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed: that did end up working. I forgot to also make the same change to a loop later on in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with `select` (which emits `empty` if its argument evaluates to `false`, i.e. there is no match), and `test` for regular expressions:

```bash
jq '.players[].name | select(test("ZZZ|temp|Failed") | not) '
```

```json
"E180TH-426-CIC-008"
"LBRTY-185-CIC-005"
```

Comment: OK, I simplified my question. Really, I'm returning a different key "id":

`jq '.players[] | if .name | contains( "ZZZ" ) then empty else .id end'`

Then there's code later on that looks for names associated with ids. so I'm filtering the "name" key but returning the value of the "id" key.

Comment: @Max Then move `.name` inside the `select` filter, and output `.id` instead: `.players[] | select(.name | test("ZZZ|temp|Failed") | not).id`